# option selecionada

Tags: php, value, option

Tenho um código que retorna dados do banco em um option, porém não consigo fazer com q o valor registrado no banco fique selecionado. Por exemplo, o option irá trazer todos os bairros cadastrados na tabela bairros. Neste Option gostaria de, além de trazer o bairro que pertence ao cliente, selecionado, também trazer as opções de bairros para alterar o mesmo, caso aja necessidade, conforme a tabela Bairros.

```
<tr>
    <td id="content_editar"><label>Bairros:</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="content_editar">
    <select name="id_bairros" id="id_bairros">

    <?php
      $identificador = $_GET['id'];

      $sql = "SELECT i.id_imagens, i.descricao, i.localizacao, i.observacao, b.nome AS bairro, FROM imagens AS i 
      INNER JOIN bairros AS b ON b.id_bairros = i.id_bairros 
      WHERE id_imagens = 'id'";

      $result_bairros = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           while($row_bairros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bairros)){
echo '<option value="'.$row_bairros['id_bairros'].'">'.$row_bairros['nome'].'</option>';
       }
?>
       </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

[image: Consulta de Bairros]

---

Na verdade, acabou não aparecendo o código todo da consulta. Segue o código completo.

```
<?php    
include "config.php";

$identificador = $_GET['id'];

$consulta_imagens = "SELECT * FROM imagens a
WHERE `id_imagens` = '$identificador'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta_imagens);
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

$id_imagens = $linha['id_imagens'];
$descricao = $linha['descricao'];
$localizacao = $linha['localizacao'];
$observacao = $linha['observacao'];
$id_bairros = $linha['id_bairros'];
$id_rotulos = $linha['id_rotulos'];
$situacao = $linha['situacao'];

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Edição de Imagens</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/editar.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">

        <?php
        include_once "topo.php"
        ?>
        <?php
        include_once "nav_on.php"
        ?>

        <div id="editar_btn_imagens">
            <div id="editar1">
                <form action="processa_edita_imagens.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="editando_imagens" id="editando_imagens">
                <p><strong>EDITAR CAMPOS DA IMAGEM</strong></p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><input type="hidden" name="id_imagens" id="id_imagens" value="<?php echo "$id_imagens" ?> "/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><label>Descrição da Imagem:</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><input type="text" name="descricao" id="descricao" value="<?php echo "$descricao" ?> "/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><label>Localização:</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><input type="text" name="localizacao" id="localizacao" value="<?php echo "$localizacao" ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><label>Ponto de Referência:</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><input type="text" name="observacao" id="observacao" value="<?php echo "$observacao" ?> "/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><label>Bairros:</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar">
                            <select name="id_bairros" id="id_bairros">

                                <?php
                                $identificador = $_GET['id'];

                                $sql = "SELECT i.id_imagens, i.descricao, i.localizacao, i.observacao, b.nome AS bairro, FROM imagens AS i 
                                INNER JOIN bairros AS b ON b.id_bairros = i.id_bairros 
                                WHERE id_imagens = 'id'";
                                print_r($sql);
                                $result_bairros = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                while($row_bairros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bairros)){
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row_bairros['id_bairros'].' selected=selected">'.$row_bairros['nome'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                    $busca_bairros = "SELECT * FROM bairros ORDER BY nome";
                                    $result_bairros = mysqli_query($conn, $busca_bairros);
                                    while($row_bairros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bairros)){
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_bairros['id_bairros'].'">'.$row_bairros['nome'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar"><label>Rótulos:</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="content_editar">
                            <select name="id_rotulos" id="id_rotulos">
                                <?php
            $identificador = $_GET['id']; // dependendo de como está trabalhando pode twer que mudar para $_POST['id']

//Criar a query
            $sql = "SELECT i.id_imagens, i.descricao, i.localizacao, i.observacao, r.nome AS rotulo, i.arquivo, i.situacao FROM imagens AS i INNER JOIN rotulos AS r ON r.id_rotulos = i.id_rotulos ORDER BY i.descricao;";

// Executa a query
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                echo '<option value="'.$linha['id_bairros'].'">'.$linha['nome'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>  

            <?php
            $busca_rotulos = "SELECT * FROM rotulos ORDER BY nome";
            $result_rotulos = mysqli_query($conn, $busca_rotulos);
            while($row_rotulos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_rotulos)){
                echo '<option value="'.$row_rotulos['id_rotulos'].'">'.$row_rotulos['nome'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="checkbox"><label>Situação:</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="checkbox"><label>Ativo</label><input type="checkbox" name="situacao" value="1" checked="TRUE"></td>
   </tr>
   </table>

   <tr>
       <td id="editar_btn_imagens"><input type="submit" name="salvar" id="salvar" value="Salvar" class="btn" /></td>
   </tr>
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <?php
       include_once 'footer.php';
    ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Faca duas consultas. Uma pegando o nome do bairro e o id daquele client. Em seguida, faca uma consulta acrescentando o restante dos bairros

Comment: Tenta incrementar sua pergunta adicionando seu html e de onde vem o valor que deve ser selecionado... De qualquer forma, você pode fazer duas consultas ou  uma sub-consulta com a lógica pra decidir se seleciona ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Na hora de montar seu `select` basta verificar em cada `option` se o ID desse bairro é igual o ID que está no registro sendo editado, o código ficaria assim:

```
<?php
    $busca_bairros = "SELECT * FROM bairros ORDER BY nome";
    $result_bairros = mysqli_query($conn, $busca_bairros);
    while($row_bairros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bairros)){
        $selected = ($id_bairros == $row_bairros['id_bairros'])?' selected':'';
        echo '<option'.$selected.' value="'.$row_bairros['id_bairros'].'">'.$row_bairros['nome'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Caso os ID's sejam iguais, ele vai marcar o `option` como selecionado.

Comment: Grande Gabriel, perfeito meu chegado, funcionou certinho. Obrigado mesmo tchê. Obrigado à todos q se dispuseram a me auxiliar.

Comment: Carlos, a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas se alguma resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour], para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
 $result_bairros = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           while($row_bairros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bairros)){
<option value="'.$row_bairros['id_bairros'].'">echo $row_bairros['id_bairros']</option>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve fazer uma consulta no banco identificando qual é o valor à ser selecionado. Após basta ir verificando no seu `while` e adicionar o `selected` caso encontrar

```
// Consulta o registro que deve estar selecionado
//$sqlSelecionado = "select de acordo com seu identificador ..."
$selected       = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSelecionado);

// Retorno de todos os bairros
$result_bairros = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row_bairros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_bairros)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row_bairros['id_bairros'].'" '. ($selected['id_bairros'] == $row_bairros['id_bairros'] ? selected = "selected" : "") .'>'.$row_bairros['nome'].'</option>';
}
```